# Pixijs: Arc Bullet Effect

Tags: javascript, pixi.js, bullet

I'm learning game making on Pixijs and am having some problems.

Currently, the projectile has followed an arc trajectory but has the problem that it is in the same position.

For example, a for loop has 10 bullets, then the bullets are in turn followed each other by a distance (eg about 10px).

Here is my current code. If you have an answer, please reply to me.

###### Note:

1. `donDanh.hieuung` : Number of bullets
2. `bullet`: container of `[i]`
3. `mucTieu.x, .y` : Target to
4. `donDanh.x, .y` : Bullet starting point

```
for (let i = 0; i < donDanh.hieuung; i++) {
    let bullet = addnewskill.getChildByName(element.id + "_" + i);
    if (bullet.time % 5 == 0) {
      bullet.texture =
        PIXI.utils.TextureCache[
          getNameSkill(
            element.name,
            element.level,
            follow.src[bullet.start]
          )
        ];

      bullet.start++;
      if (bullet.start + 1 > soKhung) {
        bullet.start = 0;
      }
    }
    bullet.time++;

  let dx = mucTieu.x - donDanh.x;
  let dy = mucTieu.y - donDanh.y;
  let distance = Math.sqrt(dx * dx + dy * dy);
  let angle = Math.atan2(dy, dx);
  let midX = (donDanh.x + mucTieu.x) / 2;
  let midY = (donDanh.y + mucTieu.y) / 2 - distance / 4;

  let bulletSpeed = 5; // speed of bullet
  let timeElapsed = bullet.time + i * 2; // time elapsed since bullet was fired
  let t = timeElapsed / (distance / bulletSpeed); // 
  let x = (1 - t) * (1 - t) * donDanh.x + 2 * (1 - t) * t * midX + t * t * mucTieu.x; // Tọa độ x của điểm trên đường cong tại thời điểm tương đối của viên đạn
  let y = (1 - t) * (1 - t) * donDanh.y + 2 * (1 - t) * t * midY + t * t * mucTieu.y +  0; // Tọa độ y của điểm trên đường cong tại thời điểm tương đối của viên đạn


  bullet.x = x ;
  bullet.y = y;

}
```

Thank you !

[image]

This is Program I want:

[image: This is Program I want]

Comment: just delay the creation and launch of each bullet using set timeout ... ie `setTimeout(()=>shoot_something(...args),i*500)`